# How to extract underlined text from a pdf using itextSharp in c#

Tags: c#, itext

How to extract underlined text from a pdf using itextSharp in c# ? Could anybody tell, is it possible ?

Comment: This is non-trivial because underlined text in pdfs is not implemented using some text attribute but instead by drawing the text normally and separately drawing a line beneath it. Thus, it is difficult to recognise whether some line underlines text or whether it has a different function and just accidentally happens to be beneath some text.

Comment: Your question might be answered if you shared a sample PDF with underlines applied in a representative way for your target PDFs.